# Linking Multiple Tables in Laravel using Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 3 tables user table, countries table, personal_details table. The structure is as follows

**Users:**

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('role');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->integer('terms');
    $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Countries:**

```
Schema::create('countries', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('countrycode');
    $table->string('countryname');
    $table->string('code');
    $table->string('flag');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Personal Details:**

```
Schema::create('personal_details', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->integer('user_id');
    $table->string('first_name');
    $table->string('last_name');
    $table->string('sex');
    $table->date('date_of_birth');
    $table->string('country');
    $table->string('freelancer_type');
    $table->text('about_me');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

On the welcome page i need to display users profiles including country and associated flag. here is the code im using

**Route**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    $category = \App\Category::all();
    $user = \App\User::all()->where('role', '==', 'Freelancer');
    $post = \App\Post::paginate(3);
    return view('welcome', compact('category', 'user', 'post'));
});
```

and the **View**

```
@foreach($user as $users)
<div class="col-lg-3 md-6 xs-6" style="text-align: center">
    <div class="card-deck">
        <div class="card shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">
            <div class="card-body">
                <img src="/profile_images/{{$users->profileimage->image}}"
                     style="width: 100px; height: 100px; border-radius: 50%">
                <p><span style="font-weight: 900; color: #009dba">{{$users->personaldetails->first_name}} {{$users->personaldetails->last_name}}</span>
                    <br/>
                    <span style="font-size: 11px">
                          {{$users->expertise->profession}}</span>
                </p>
                <p style="font-size: 11px">{{$users->personaldetails->country}},
                    ZAR{{$users->expertise->hourly_rate}}/hr</p>
                <hr>
                <p style="font-size: 11px">{{str_limit($users->personaldetails->about_me, $limit = 80, $end =
                    '...')}}</p>
                {{$users->personaldetails->country->flag}}
                <div style="padding-top: 10px"></div>
                <a href="/users/{{$users->id}}">
                    <button>View Profile</button>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

I am receiving the error Trying to get property 'flag' of non-object. Please help

Comment: I really suggest having a quick read of the docs, literally 20 min reading of the basics and you would not have to ask this question.  [Start with Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent), just skim the more complex stuff you don't think you'll need.

Answer (score 0):

In this line `{{$users->personaldetails->country->flag}}` you are calling for `relational` data. Your `relational` data is working in chain. First `$user` is calling relation of `personal_details` table. In the `personal_details` table you have stored `user_id` so the relationship is working. But when you are chaining `countries` table using `personaldetails` there will be no result as no relationship exists. You can see that your `countries` table holds information of only about country, no `id` of `personal_details` is stored as `foreign key` in your `countries` table. If you want to retrieve data through relations you must store id of `personal_details` table as `foreign key` in `countries` table. So if you store `personal_detail_id` in your country table, there should be no problem.

Your `countries` table should look like the following:

```
Schema::create('countries', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('personal_detail_id');
        $table->string('countrycode');
        $table->string('countryname');
        $table->string('code');
        $table->string('flag');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Comment: The country table just holds a list of countries and their flags . So on the view of the Personal Details form there is a dropdown that picks country name from the country table

Comment: Yes, but if you want to retrieve data through relationship you should store `personal_detail_id` in `countries` table. I am just pointing out why you are getting the error. Isn't this why you posted here?

Comment: ok i hear you but its not possible for me to do that as countries table does not store the selected country by a user it is a static table that only countries a list of all the countries in the world. So literally the table is used for the dropdown select option on the Personal Details form. The selected country name is the stored in the personal details table. i hope that is clear

Comment: Then you will have to query for it rather than using relational data. From `personal_details` you can get the country, so you should be able to create a `where()` method query from it. Hope this helps.